# Processing more than 100k records of data

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

I am developing spring-mvc application.

I have an requirement of processing more than 100k records of data. And I can't make it database dependent so I have to implement all the logic in java.

For now I am creating number of threads and assigning say 1000 records to each thread to process.

I am using `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

List item

**Question:**

1. Suggested number of threads that I should use.
2. - Should I equally divide number of records among threads or
   - Should I give predefined number of records to each thread and increase the number of threads?
3. ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is ok or I should use something else?
4. Should I maintain the record ids which is assigned to each thread in java or in database? (Note : If using database then I have make extra database call for each record and update it after processing that record)

Can any one please suggest me best practices in this scenario.

Any kind of suggestion will be great.

***Note:*** Execution time is main concern.

**Update:**

Processing include hug number of database calls.
Means you can consider it as searching done in java. Taking one record, then comparing(in java) that record with other records from db. Then again taking another record and do the same.

Comment: What is the balance between compute and I/O? If you just run it with one thread, how busy is the processor (or are the processors)? There are costs to multithreading - the OS may do a better job of prefetch if you read in order.

Comment: It all depends on what "processing a record" means. Is the task IO-bound or CPU-bound? If you need a database connection per thread, how many database connections do you have in your pool? Have you measured the time it takes using one thread? Because 100K is not *that* much.

Comment: Please find my updated question.

Comment: For now I am developing in local, now I can't say how many number of connections will I have on server. My biggest time problem is database calls.

Comment: 100K database call (even with threads) will take a huge amount of time. Can't you rethink the process ?

Comment: @yunandtidus, I have preference of executing code in db itself rather in java. but my requirement is to support multiple database, so I have to make it such a way that only CRUD operations are performed on db, and other things in java. How much amount of data can I store in java cache, so that I can fetch large data at start to avoid small database queries.

Answer (score 1):

In order to process huge amount of data, you can use Spring Batch framework.
Check this [Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/index.html).
Wiki [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Batch).

Answer (score 0):

ExecutorService should be fine for you, no need to use spring. But the thread number will be a trick. I can only say, it depends, why not try out to figure out the optimized number?